# Laravel Url 404 and indexing on server

Tags: laravel-4, indexing, cpanel, server

Hello everyone I am attempting to get a server up and running using Cpanel, now at first i couldn't get the home page to show because i couldn't index it correctly so i simply uses a redirect, witch then brought me to this problem when ever the pages displays it says  http://blahblah.com/Laravel/Public and when i click on a href it directs me to http://blahblach.com/Student. I have read several articles that say to edit the apache.conf but i cant find that in the server files and i also cant find were it's pointing the default location. So any help with one or both of these problems will be a great deal of help. Thank you.

Comment: Good article on using Laravel 4 on a shared host here: http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello everyone so what i did as suggested from the article that Ben so kindly provided me with I dumped my application onto the root then went into the file "path.php" and removed the public path and then i went into the index and removed the dots in front of bootstap and boom done    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnGUD1VTxuQ   <--- explains it all